# Js : onclick button not triggering

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

A set of buttons is no longer working and I can't work out why.

The site is using Joomla and SP Page Builder Pro.

There are 3 buttons that when clicked will change the price table. However these no longer work and there's no errors in the console.

If I enter the function name into the console, the script will trigger and change the table.

Debugging steps:
Updated Joomla 
Disabled non required plugins
Cleared cache
Checked code is being loaded
Checked for java conflicts

Many thanks

Comment: Your site is taking so long to load :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your buttons are using the `on-click` attribute, which isn't valid. You need to use `onclick` instead.

Replace:

```
on-click="tripleCoverDlFold1()"
```

with:

```
onclick="tripleCoverDlFold1()"
```